# mist or wallet for macos can't connect to private-net

Tags: wallets, mist, macos

mist or wallet for macos(version 0.11.1) can't connect to private-net.

using command: ./Ethereum\ Wallet --rpc http://localhost:8545

but mist or wallet (version 0.9.3) works.  why？ tks！